# UPDATED: Rails form with nested_fields and multiple has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, accepts-nested-attributes

I have the following models:

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord

  # Other validations 

  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, update_only: true

end 

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :country
  has_one :state
  has_one :city
  has_one :suburb

  belongs_to :property
end
```

The relationships for `country`, `state`, `city` and `suburb` are all linked with a `has_many` and `belongs_to` between each other.

### The problem is :

On my `properties/_form.html.erb` file I'm trying to create the address with nested `fields_for` the `:address` and on those nested fields using `options_from_collection_for_select`. Code below:

```
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= form.label :address, "Dirección", class: "col-sm-2 control-label"%>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
          <%= form.fields_for :address do |ff| %>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <select class="form-control" name="property[address_attributes][country_id]" >
                  <%= options_from_collection_for_select(Country.all, :id, :name) %>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <select class="form-control"  name="property[address_attributes][state_id]" >
                  <%= options_from_collection_for_select(State.all, :id, :name) %>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <select class="form-control"  name="property[address_attributes][city_id]" >
                  <%= options_from_collection_for_select(City.all, :id, :name) %>
                </select>
```

And getting this error on submit:

[image: submit error]

## Update 1

So I've changed my form a bit with this:

```
<%= ff.select :country, options_from_collection_for_select(Country.all, :id, :name) %>
```

On all of my relationships and now the error I get is:

```
Country(#70194352893700) expected, got "1" which is an instance of String(#70194311847460)
```

[image: Country expected got whis is an instance of String]

## Update 2:

Here is the code on my `schema.rb` describing my `addresses` table:

```
  create_table "addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "street"
    t.integer "number"
    t.integer "zip_code"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "property_id"
    t.integer "countries_id"
    t.integer "states_id"
    t.integer "cities_id"
    t.integer "suburbs_id"
    t.index ["cities_id"], name: "index_addresses_on_cities_id"
    t.index ["countries_id"], name: "index_addresses_on_countries_id"
    t.index ["property_id"], name: "index_addresses_on_property_id"
    t.index ["states_id"], name: "index_addresses_on_states_id"
    t.index ["suburbs_id"], name: "index_addresses_on_suburbs_id"
  end
```

Comment: Try changing `ff.select :country` to `ff.select :country_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that your `address` *table* doesn't have a `country_id` field on it even though your `Address` *model* says that there should be a relationship.

You can verify by looking at `db/schema.rb`.

If the `address` table is missing that column you can do something like this on the command line to add it:

```
rails g migration add_country_id_to_addresses country:belongs_to
```

And then run `rake db:migrate`.

There's a little bit of "magic" involved in the instructions above, so here's an explanation.

`rails g migration` is telling Rails to generate a database migration.

`add_country_to_addresses` is the name of the migration. You could also use `AddCountryToAddresses` if you're into CamelCase over snake_case. If rails finds `_to_*` (or `To*`) at the end of your migration name it can infer the name of the table to generate the migration for. In this case the `addresses` table.

`country:belongs_to` tells Rails that the migration should link the `addresses` table to the `countries` table. It will add a `country_id` column and (depending on your db settings) will generate an index and/or foreign key for the new column.

### Update

Your `db/schema.rb` shows that you do not, in fact, have a `country_id` field on that table. You have a `countries_id` field.

To fix this you can generate a blank migration:

```
rails g migration rename_countries_id_on_addresses
```

And then edit the migration to contain:

```
change_table :addresses do |t|
  t.rename :countries_id, :country_id
end
```

And then run migrations:

```
rake db:migrate
```

You can find more info about changing tables with migrations here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-tables

Comment: Hi Jeremy, i've changed my code a bit and now i get another error saying that: `Country(#70194352893700) expected, got "1" which is an instance of String(#70194311847460)` I will update my question in a moment.

Comment: I've updated the question already, any pointers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you verified that your table does have a `country_id` column? Can you post the section of `db/schema.rb` that describes your `addresses` table?